# Second lookup opportunity on account

Tags: opportunity, related-list, opportunity-lineitem

I made a second lookup from opportunity to account and gave the related lis another name to separate the opportunities yet if i add a opportunitiy to one of the related lists it appears in both, how can this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out you have to make 2 lookups to account. With procesbuilder trigger from opportunity to change the 2 lookups to account id field and hide the standard related list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, one Opportunity record is related to an Account with Master-Detail relationship and other Account is related to Lookup relationship.

And with the same Opportunity you are linking both the accounts. That's why it is behaving like that.

Comment: Ok but how can i separate these?

Comment: exactly you have not shared the use case, if you want to link other Account as lookup you can create a junction object and link Opportunity and Account, that way related list are separated

Comment: or otherwise, do not expose other lookup related relationships into that Lookup Account's page layout

Comment: Usecase: I want to separate 2 different opportunity recodtypes which i have in 2 separate related list. So 1 recordtype in one related list and another recortype in another related list.

Comment: then you can create 2 separate page layout and do the assignment

Comment: This gives me 2 different page layouts but the related lists keep showing the same opportunities??

Comment: thats natural since you are linking same Opportunity to 2 accounts

Comment: I have 1 account with sevveral opportunities from which 2 opportunity record types all show up in one related list I want to seperate these by the second related list. At moment if I add an opportunity to the lookup related list I made it still shows up in the master detail related list.